# Embeding symbols from a swf created with mxmlc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bytecode

In my project i use swfs bundled with resources. These bundles are created from another utility application. Application creates an Package.as file with [Embed] tags puts all resources to the the same directory and runs mxmlc to compile bundle swf.

Bundled swf works like a charm. I can instantiate assets.

However i want to implement another utility to edit these bundles ( to add and remove resources) 
Here is the problem. Since this bundle.swf is not created from Flash i cannot use:

```
[Embed ( source="oldbundle.swf", symbol="Package_res1" ) ]  // ( "Package_res1" is class name of resource in bundle")
```

in creating new swf. mxmlc returns symbol not found errors.

For bytearray assets i found a solution. I write bytearrays to disk, then use those files for embed. However i cannot do the same thing for vector graphics that were added as symbol from Flash swf into the original bundle. If i write bitmapdatas on disk i would lose vectorness ( Not sure if it is a word :) ). SVG is not a complete option to substute flash symbol.

Using [as3swf](https://github.com/claus/as3swf), i inspected the bundle swf and saw SymbolClass tag. All of the assets are defined there. I don't know why embed tag cannot find the symbol. Difference with bundled.swf symbol and Flash swf symbol is, one extends SpriteAsset( an flex framework object) other extends sprite

What can i do to use older swf as embed source for new swf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also make it work with member variables by extracting the name of the class auto-generated by `mxmlc`. For example, here's the same `Bundle` class again:

```
// Bundle.as
package
{

import flash.display.*;

public class Bundle extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source='image.jpg')]
    private var imageClass:Class;

    public function Bundle()
    {
        var image:DisplayObject = new imageClass();
        addChild(image);
    }
}

}
```

Now if you compile it with `-keep`:

```
mxmlc Bundle.as -keep
```

You can find the generated code in a file called `Bundle_imageClass.as` in the `generated` directory, with the following contents:

```
package 
{

import mx.core.BitmapAsset;

[ExcludeClass]
[Embed(_resolvedSource="/Users/manish/Code/test/image.jpg", _column="6", source="image.jpg", exportSymbol="Bundle_imageClass", _line="9", _file="/Users/manish/Code/test/Bundle.as")]

public class Bundle_imageClass extends mx.core.BitmapAsset 
{
    public function Bundle_imageClass() 
    { 
        super(); 
    }

}

}
```

Look for `exportSymbol`. That's your symbol name for embedding into other SWFs.

Now the `Application` class:

```
// Application.as
package
{

import flash.display.*;

public class Application extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source='Bundle.swf', symbol='Bundle_imageClass')]
    private var imageClass:Class;

    public function Application()
    {
        var image:DisplayObject = new imageClass();
        addChild(image);
    }
}

}
```

Use the exact value you find in `exportSymbol` in the generated code (in this case, `Bundle_imageClass`), and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Your symbols need to be public.

Here's an example. First, the original SWF, let's call it Bundle.swf.

```
// Bundle.as
package
{

import flash.display.*;

public class Bundle extends Sprite
{
    public function Bundle()
    {
        var image:DisplayObject = new Image();
        addChild(image);
    }
}

}
```

This is where `Image` is defined:

```
// Image.as
package
{

import flash.display.*;

[Embed(source='image.jpg')]
public class Image extends Bitmap
{
}

}
```

Now if you compile `Bundle.as` and open `Bundle.swf`, you'll see your image.

Next, we want to reuse it in a new SWF, let's call it Application.swf.

```
// Application.as
package
{

import flash.display.*;

public class Application extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source='Bundle.swf', symbol='Image')]
    private var imageClass:Class;

    public function Application()
    {
        var image:DisplayObject = new imageClass();
        addChild(image);
    }
}

}
```

Compile `Application.as` and open `Application.swf`. You'll see the image again.

It works because `Image` is public.

Comment: The difference with my version and this is mine uses embed tag over variable yours uses it over class definition. I will give it a try

Comment: @altunsercan I've added another answer for working with member variables instead of separate classes.

Comment: I tested your answer and it worked. However when i change my code it wouldn't work. I am suspecting the problem is in calling mxmlc.exe from air application. Maybe compiler parameters.

Comment: @altunsercan Great! I see you're new to the site. If my answer worked for you, you can "upvote" it, and maybe even "accept" it if it solved your problem.

Comment: The code works for bitmap embeds like .png, .jpg.. However it doesn't work if the embed class extends sprite.

Comment: @altunsercan For normal classes, I think you'll have to embed the entire SWF (sadly), then use `Loader.loadBytes()` to load it, then get to the loader's `ApplicationDomain` and use `ApplicationDomain.getDefinition()` to extract the class.